# How to display one SQL column as two seperate columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot-table

I have an SQL table storing phone numbers , and phone types , customer_id is a foreign key relating back to a customer table

```
NumberID   | phone_number | phone_type|customer_id
         1 | 011111       | phone1    |1
         2 | 022222       | phone2    |1
```

Im trying to display it as below using sqlite

```
customer_id|  phone1    |phone2
          1|   011111   |022222
```

Im not sure what the right way to go about it is , should i be using self joins?

Comment: What if the customer has three, four, ... or 20 phones? Do you want 20 columns?

Comment: I found another question that was also tagged with sqlite, that shows the general technique of doing pivot tables. That other question also involves sum(), which is not relevant to your case, but otherwise it's applicable. The technique is identical in other brands of SQL database, so you can find other answers by following the [tag:pivot-table] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN phone_type = 'phone1' THEN phone_number END) phone1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN phone_type = 'phone2' THEN phone_number END) phone2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer_id,
       max(case when phone_type = 'phone1' then phone_number end) as phone1,
       max(case when phone_type = 'phone2' then phone_number end) as phone2
from t
group by customer_id;
```